# Plotly Express timeline for Gantt Chart with integer xaxis?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I'm using plotly express timeline to produce a Gantt chart following this example: https://medium.com/dev-genius/gantt-charts-in-python-with-plotly-e7213f932f1e

It automatically sets the x-axis to use dates but I'd actually like to just use integers (i.e. Project Kick-Off +1, Project Kick-Off +6, etc).

Is there a way to make a timeline plot NOT use dates for the xaxis?

If I try using integers it'll treat them like milliseconds.

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: Not quite. I still need to dig into it a ittle bit but it's close to being the soluton I need. Thanks!

Comment: Would you consider marking my suggestion as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 12):

#### The answer:

Yes, it's possible! Just give integers as start and end "dates", calculate the difference between them (`delta`), and make these changes to your `fig`:

```
fig.layout.xaxis.type = 'linear'
fig.data[0].x = df.delta.tolist()
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### The details:

There actually is a way to achieve this, although the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/) state that:

> The px.timeline function by default sets the X-axis to be of
> type=date, so it can be configured like any time-series chart.

And therefore every other functionality in `px.timeline()` seems to revolve around that fact. But if you just ignore that and use integers as values for `Start` and `Finish`, then you can tweak a few attributes to get what you want. You just need to calculate the differences between each `Start` and `Stop`. For example like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start=1, Finish=4),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start=2, Finish=6),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start=3, Finish=10)
])
df['delta'] = df['Finish'] - df['Start']
```

And then tweak a little further:

```
fig.layout.xaxis.type = 'linear'
fig.data[0].x = df.delta.tolist()
```

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start=1, Finish=4),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start=2, Finish=6),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start=3, Finish=10)
])
df['delta'] = df['Finish'] - df['Start']

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") 

fig.layout.xaxis.type = 'linear'
fig.data[0].x = df.delta.tolist()
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 8):

I think this is much simpler solution than above when we have to specify `color`

```
for d in fig.data:
  filt = df['color'] == d.name
  d.x = df[filt]['Delta'].tolist()
```

Comment: I am sorry but you are not answering the question

Comment: FYI this is additional comment to vestland's answer, and if you try out yourself, you would find out it is much simpler than overwriting process_dataframe_timeline function like amos's answer.

Comment: This is indeed a useful comment, as it simplifies the solution a lot! The problem in the initial solution is in `fig.data[0].x`, so this 0 index will fix only first series of bars and the rest of them will be invisible. A couple of lines mentioned here fixes this issue for me without patching plotly code.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the other answer listed here, but that doesn't work if I specify a `color`. If I try, the data `fig.data` has multiple `Bar` objects, and I don't think it contains the data necessary to assign all the deltas. However, I did find that I could monkeypatch [plotly code](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/03979d105c65dda3df3a155322eaff18f203b03f/packages/python/plotly/plotly/express/_core.py#L1621-L1643) to not convert it to time objects and I get the correct result:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

def my_process_dataframe_timeline(args):
    """
    Massage input for bar traces for px.timeline()
    """
    print("my method")
    args["is_timeline"] = True
    if args["x_start"] is None or args["x_end"] is None:
        raise ValueError("Both x_start and x_end are required")

    x_start = args["data_frame"][args["x_start"]]
    x_end = args["data_frame"][args["x_end"]]

    # note that we are not adding any columns to the data frame here, so no risk of overwrite
    args["data_frame"][args["x_end"]] = (x_end - x_start)
    args["x"] = args["x_end"]
    del args["x_end"]
    args["base"] = args["x_start"]
    del args["x_start"]
    return args
px._core.process_dataframe_timeline = my_process_dataframe_timeline

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start=1, Finish=4, color="1"),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start=2, Finish=6, color="2"),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start=3, Finish=10, color="1")
])
df['delta'] = df['Finish'] - df['Start']

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="color")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") 

fig.layout.xaxis.type = 'linear'
fig.show()
```

Obviously not desirable to do this... it would be nice to get formal support.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate how the answer from JounghooLee works, I want to add this example

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start=1, Finish=10),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start=3, Finish=6),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start=3, Finish=10)
])

df['delta'] = df['Finish'] - df['Start']

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Task")


print(fig.data[0].x)
print(fig.data[1].x)
print(fig.data[2].x)

a = [True, False, False]
b = [False, True, False]
c = [False, False, True]

aSeries = pd.Series(a)
bSeries = pd.Series(b)
cSeries = pd.Series(c)

fig.layout.xaxis.type = 'linear'

# the dataFrame df is filtered by the pandas series, to add the specific delta to each of the bars
fig.data[0].x = df[aSeries]['delta'].tolist()
fig.data[1].x = df[bSeries]['delta'].tolist()
fig.data[2].x = df[cSeries]['delta'].tolist()

print(fig.data[0].x)
print(fig.data[1].x)
print(fig.data[2].x)


fig.show()
```

The `prints` give the following output:

```
[0.]
[0.]
[0.]
(9,)
(3,)
(7,)
```

and the `fig.data` contains three bars

[image]

If there is no `color` assigned, it does not work, because then `fig.data` contains just 1 bar

[image]

The `print(fig.data[0].x)` returns

```
[0. 0. 0.]
```

in this case.

See also this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71141827/7447940

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a plotly barplot and use the `base` argument to indicate where to put the bar start and the `x` value would be the duration of the task:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(task="Job A", start=1, end=4),
    dict(task="Job B", start=2, end=6),
    dict(task="Job C", start=3, end=10)
])
df['delta'] = df['end'] - df['start']

fig = px.bar(df, 
base = "start",
x = "delta",
y = "task",
orientation = 'h'
)

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.show()
```

[image]

The barplot also accepts the `color` argument and correctly groups the tasks by the column you indicate, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(task="Job A", start=1, end=4, color = "A"),
    dict(task="Job B", start=2, end=6, color = "B"),
    dict(task="Job C", start=3, end=10, color = "A")
])
df['delta'] = df['end'] - df['start']

fig = px.bar(df, 
base = "start",
x = "delta",
y = "task",
color = "color",
orientation = 'h'
)

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.show()
```

[image]